# Opening and closing tags in HTML

Tags: html

I am just beginner with HTML. So, sorry if its very basic question.

So far I know that for each tag we should open and make sure to close it for example:

```
<span id="xxx" class="yyy">Hello</span>
```

Today I saw something like this:

```
<span id="xxx" class="yyy">X</a>
```

can someone explain please

Comment: Yes, it is wrong but the browser accepting it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> <span id="xxx" class="yyy">X</a>
> ```

This is an error and browsers will attempt to recover from it so that users don't get a broken experience.

Some elements have optional start tags. Some elements have optional end tags. `span` and `a` are not among those elements.

Comment: As far as I know there is no html element with an optional start tag.

Comment: I would say "Depending on Doctype, some tags have optional end tags"

Comment: @mplungjan — Maybe if you use XHTML instead of HTML, but not within HTML AFAIK.

Comment: The w3 validator does not accept a document without html and/or body start tag. Please provide me with a link to html specification, which shows that the validator has to accept the document `<p>Hello.</p></body></html>` as valid to fulfil the html specification.

Comment: [W3Org HTML5 8.1.2.4 Optional tags - Certain tags can be omitted.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission)

Comment: The validator does accept such a document, I'll put together an example in a moment. The example you gave is not valid since the Doctype and title are required.

Comment: [A document that validates](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest-cases.dorward.me.uk%2Fstackoverflow%2F21135377%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

Comment: And [how to read the HTML 4 DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.3) mentions `O` as indicating *Whether the element's tags are optional* and the [HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.3) has `<!ELEMENT HTML O O` so the start and end tags may be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

The markup `<span id="xxx" class="yyy">X</a>` is invalid in any context by HTML syntax rules: even if there is a an opening `<a>` tag before this, with no matching end tag so far, the `a` element cannot be closed this way, since there would be an open `span` element inside it, and end tag omission is not allowed for `span`.

What actually happens depends on the context. If there was an `<a>` start tag, the end tag `</a>` would close it, and, as error recovery, the browser would implicitly close the `span` tag as well.

If there were no `<a>` start tag, the end tag `</a>` would be skipped, as not matching anything, and the browser would keep looking for an `</span>` tag, until it encounters a closing tag for an outer element or a start tag for an element that cannot be contained in a `span` element, such as `<p>`.

A simple demo:

```
<style>span { background: green }</style>
<a><span id="xxx" class="yyy">X</a> Hello world
<hr>
<span id="xxx" class="yyy">Y</a> Hi again
<p>Done.
```

Here “X” will have green background, as it is taken as the sole content of the first `span`. There is also green background for “Y Hi again”, as that will parsed as the content of the second `span`.

So it gets dirty and messy. And although the error recovery is rather consistent across browsers, and being standardized in HTML5, it’s best to avoid it, by using valid markup. You can use validators such as http://validator.w3.org to check your markup.